# Is this multithreaded iteration safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, iterator

I have a collection and I want to spawn a number of Threads to do some heavy work on its elements. Each element of the collection must be processed one and only one time. I want to keep synchronization as minimal as possible and I came up with the following code:

```
//getting the iterator is actually more complicated in my specific case
final Iterator it = myCollection.terator(); 
Thread[] threads = new Thread[numThreads];

for( int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++ ) {
    threads[i] = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Object obj = null;
            while(true) {
                synchronized (it) {
                    if(it.hasNext())
                        obj = it.next();
                    else
                        return;
                }
                //Do stuff with obj
            }
        }
    });
    threads[i].start();
}

for (Thread t : threads)
    try {
        t.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**NOTE:** No threads will ever modify the collection by adding or removing items while 'doing stuff with obj'

This code is quite different from examples that I found around where people tend to synchronize over the collection itself, use `Collection.synchronizedStuff..`, or they just synchronize over the entire iteration. During my research I also found possibly better alternatives implemented using `ThreadPoolExecutor` but let's forget about it for a second...

Is the code above safe considering the note 1 above? If not, why?

Comment: So long as note 1 remains true it will be ok. Executers are definitely the way to go for things like this though.

Comment: If you are trying to keep your `synchronized` block small for performance reasons, then you might be surprised how much time is spend during creation and execution of each (native) thread, use executors instead as proposed.

Comment: Your concept code looks fine. Should work good. Access to the iterator (including checking and reading object) is synchronized, so no problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't use synchronisation at all.

I would have a loop which add tasks to an ExecutorService.

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads);

for(final MyType mt: myCollection)
    es.submit(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           doStuffWith(mt);
       }
    });
es.shutdown();
es.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
```

If you remove the need to create and shutdown the thread pool it is even shorter.

Comment: I believe it would work if your `mycollection` is not changed.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to make myCollection final and change the code as

```
 public void run() {
       Object obj = null;
       for (Object e : myCollection) {
           obj = e;
       }
```

for-each creates a new Iterator in each Thread so no synchronziation is needed.

Comment: hmmm... With this code each Thread will do stuff with every Object in the collection while I need each object to be manipulated only once. Also, the enhanced for loop uses an iterator internally (it should call both hasNext() and next()) and without synchronization the code might break.

Comment: create a iterator for every thread , i don't think this is a good idea . it's a waste of resource brings lot of overhead .